# Return html tags from json without converting to ascii in express

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, express

I want to store HTML tags in my JSON file. This JSON file it's like a database for my static Express app, which can store blogposts, text, pages, etc.

```
var express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router();

exports.fsAsync = function fsAsync(callback) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../database/data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw callback(err);
    callback(null, JSON.parse(data));
  });
};

/* GET Contact page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fsAsync(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render('404', {
        title: 'Error 404'
      });
    }
    var contact = data[2].contact;
    res.render('contact', {
      data: contact
    });
  });
});
```

JSON file specific part:

```
  {
    "contact": {
      "body": "<p>This is the Contact Page!<br />But maybe I want to store some <a href=\"#\">links</a> in my text also!</p>"
    }
  },
```

Which is converting the html tags in my JSON to ascii:

```
<main class="contact">
  <article>
    &lt;p&gt;This is the Contact Page!&lt;br /&gt;But maybe I want to store some &lt;a href&#x3D;&quot;#&quot;&gt;links&lt;/a&gt; in my text also!&lt;/p&gt;
  </article>
</main><!-- main.about-me -->
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

The templating engine is `express-handlebars`:

```
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance
  helpers: {
    // register hbs helpers in res.locals' context which provides this.locale
    __: function() { return i18n.__.apply(this, arguments); },
    __n: function() { return i18n.__n.apply(this, arguments); }
  }
}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Comment: Which template engine is used into your project?

Comment: It's `express-handlebars`. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With handlebars you may get the raw HTML output using the triple `{{{ }}}` brackets

```
<main class="contact">
  <article>
   {{{ body }}}
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! I didn't know that! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the template engine that it is html,
in [dust](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/using-filters/) `s` filter will turn of automatic html encoding:

```
<main class="contact">
  <article>
   {body|s}
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with `express-handlebars`? I really like this templating engine. Edit: Someone already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to store html code inside of a json. 
I used this website to format the html and escape the necessary characters.

http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html

Not sure if this is what your looking for but, cheers!